# Error in Linux Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm having a task of taking the first frame of the video and uploading it to AWS S3 as an image and using the following library to achieve the task.

But getting the following error in AWS EC2 ARM based server: `Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil`

It is working

- In windows and aws linux 64-bit(x86) image for server such as (t2.large,t3.large)

But it is not working for

**- ARM based image for server such as (m6g.large).**

The following is my pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2-1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2-1.5.5</version>
            <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

**I'm running jenkins in a windows server and building the project using the same. copying/deploying it in linux server via SSH post the build.**

i have tried the following:

- Added JVM variable -Dplatform.dependencies while building my project
- This is my goal in the jenkins-maven project
- `--projects wc-admin -U --also-make clean install -DskipTests=true -Dplatform.dependencies`
- Added ffmpeg-platform dependency, but the same error
- Complied in Linux environment and deployed, but the same error.

I'm unable to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2-1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

These are the changes i did to make it working again.